# oracle xmlparser v2 - exception while transforming an xmlDocument to xls stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xslt

I tried many combination the resolve this exception but in vain:
This line is throwing the exception:

```
aXsl = processor.newXSLStylesheet(xmlDocument);

oracle.xml.xslt.XSLException: XML-22009: (Error) Attribute '{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}:version' not found in 'Address'.
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.flushErrors(XSLStylesheet.java:1845)
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.endContent(XSLStylesheet.java:394)
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLBuilder.endDocument(XSLBuilder.java:304)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument.reportSAXEvents(XMLDocument.java:1541)
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLProcessor.newXSLStylesheet(XSLProcessor.java:628)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLProcessor.newXSLStylesheet(XSLProcessor.java:355)
    at com.ei.commons.transformers.infoarchitect.IAXsltHandler.buildAddressXslt(IAXsltHandler.java:124)
    at com.ei.commons.transformers.infoarchitect.TestFieldsAtRuntime.main(TestFieldsAtRuntime.java:818)
```

here is the xml sample, my objective is to get an XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Address> 
  <physicalAddress>
    <streetNumber>2</streetNumber>
    <streetName>Queen St</streetName>
    <buildingName>MF Shopping Centre</buildingName>
    </physicalAddress>
</Address>
```

Comment: Show us a sample of your xml document and the xslt script

Comment: This looks to me like `xmlDocument` is the XML you're trying to transform rather than the stylesheet you're using to transform it.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I started my weekend earlier (work function)

Comment: here is the xml sample : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Address> 
  <physicalAddress>
    <streetNumber>2</streetNumber>
    <streetName>Queen St</streetName>
    <buildingName>MF Shopping Centre</buildingName>
    </physicalAddress>
</Address>

Comment: So basically, I'm trying to get an xslt out of that xml and return it to the caller. It's my first time using the oracle xml parser.

Comment: is it possible to generate an xslt on the fly given the xmldocument as input. That's my goal.